# How can a singularity have infinite density?

Tags: black-holes, density, singularities

I've heard many times that black holes have infinite density at their center, but I've also heard astronomers quote mass estimates for black holes. How could the singularity have infinite density if it has a finite mass?

EDIT: Also, if the singularity has a size above zero, what is it?

Comment: The singularity has zero volume and all the mass is supposed to be concentrated in there. In reality, of course, the singularity simply means that we need a better theory than the one that predicts it.

Comment: Recall: d = m/v. That's also why they say a black hole is where God divides by 0.

Comment: As skill patrol is simply stating, infinite density would mean one of two things. Either the mass is infinite or the volume is zero. In this case, an infinitely dense black hole is meant to imply zero volume but finite mass

Comment: A singularity, by definition, does not have a size (or other appropriately associated property) above zero. That's what makes it a singularity, which is simply an occurrence in mathematics where the denominator drops to zero.